# Calculo percentual de horas

Tags: php

Como calcular percentual entre dois horários?

Tentei assim e não foi:

```
$tempo_total= "00:10:00";
$tempo_realizado= "00:05:00";

$percent= round((strtotime($tempo_realizado)/strtotime($tempo_total))*100);
```

Não funciona.

Comment: Veja se [**essa resposta**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5723075/1244639) ajuda.

Comment: Tente formatar o título da pergunta como questão (terminada em "?" e tudo). Ex.: "Como calcular o percentual de hora em PHP?"

Comment: Na verdade o título dispensa *PHP* pois já contém a tag correta.

Comment: Ainda não parece uma pergunta. Tente de novo e.e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nesse caso, eu penso que deve converter para segundos os tempos e dai sim fazer o calculo.

```
$tempo_total= "00:10:00";
$empo_realizado= "00:05:00";

$tt = time_to_sec($tempo_total);
$tr = time_to_sec($tempo_realizado);

$percent = round(($tr / $tt) * 100);

echo $percent;

function time_to_sec($time) {
    $hours = substr($time, 0, -6);
    $minutes = substr($time, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($time, -2);

    return $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}
```

Pelos testes que fiz aqui funcionou, e nesse caso retornou 50 que pelo que entendi, seria 50% do tempo realizado.

Answer (score 3):

Até o momento eu nunca experimentei de um caso em que usar a ferramenta certa seria mais complicado do que usar a errada.

Senta que lá vem a estória...

Para esse tipo de cálculo você deveria utilizar a famosa multiplicação cruzada que aprendemos no Ensino Fundamental:

```
A --- B
C --- D
```

No seu caso, essas variáveis representariam:

- **A** o Tempo Total
- **B** o percentual do Tempo Total (sempre 100)
- **C** o Tempo Realizado
- **D** o valor da equação que você precisa descobrir

Nessas horas o elefante do PHP estaria bramindo que já que você está trabalhando com noções de tempo você deveria usar a classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime), mas muita calma nessa hora porque não é assim tão fácil, veja:

```
$total      = "00:10:00";
$running    = "00:05:00";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $total   ) -> getTimestamp();
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $running ) -> getTimestamp();
```

O senso comum nos leva a criar os objetos DateTime a partir do formato de tempo **H:i:s**. E como não podemos de forma sensata operar as horas, minutos e segundos, obtemos o *timestamp* de cada um deles para trabalharmos apenas com os segundos.

Mas ao aplicarmos esses valores na fórmula matemática:

```
$x = ( ( 100 * $dt2 ) / $dt1 );
```

Obtemos como resultado **97.368421052632**

*What?* o.O

A implementação está correta, pode conferir na calculadora, mas alguma coisa está bagunçando os resultados e o culpado não é o mordomo, e sim o *timezone*.

A grande maioria das instalações locais do PHP têm a diretiva **date.timezone** comentada ou sem um valor válido o que faz com que qualquer script dispare o seguinte **Warning**

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

E, para silenciar esse erro, conforme o próprio orienta, 99% das vezes iniciamos o script por invocar a função [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) para definir um *timezone*. E é justamente o uso dessa função que faz o bolo desandar.

Quando criamos nossos objetos DateTime e obtivemos os *timestamps*, os inteiros retornados levam em consideração o *timezone* definido pela função acima.

Para resolver esse problema temos duas alternativas:

1. Subtrair os segundos obtidos dos segundos do marco zero da [Era Unix](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix), ou seja, 1º de Janeiro de 1970 às 00:00:00
2. Definir de forma explícita um *timezone* cujo *offset* seja zero

A primeira opção é ligeiramente mais custosa para a Aplicação pois requer a criação de um terceiro objeto DateTime:

```
$start      = "00:00:00";
$total      = "00:10:00";
$running    = "00:05:00";

$dt0 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $start   ) -> getTimestamp();
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $total   ) -> getTimestamp();
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $running ) -> getTimestamp();
```

Assim temos o que subtrair de cada um dos dois que já tínhamos:

```
$x = ( ( 100 * ( $dt2 - $dt0 ) ) / ( $dt1 - $dt0 ) ); // 50
```

A segunda opção é mais eficiente, mas não nem de longe é óbvia, pra variar.

[DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), assim como o construtor da classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime), aceita um terceiro argumento, um objeto [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/DateTimeZone) para que possamos efetuar as operações com um *offset* diferente daquele gerado por [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

Parece simples, não? Qual a dificuldade de instanciar mais um objeto?

```
$total      = "00:10:00";
$running    = "00:05:00";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $total,   new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ) -> getTimestamp();
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $running, new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ) -> getTimestamp();

$x = ( ( 100 * $dt2 ) / $dt1 );
```

Mas o resultado obtido... **99.999978800777**.

*What?* o.O

Ainda estou procurando informações concretas e mais detalhadas mas o que tenho para o momento é que para que funcione como esperado devemos criar o os objetos [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) utilizando a notação completa (ou no mínimo de data e hora), da [Era Unix](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix), ou seja, para seu tempo total, **1970-01-01 00:10:00**:

```
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $total,   new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ) -> getTimestamp();
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $running, new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ) -> getTimestamp();

$x = ( ( 100 * $dt2 ) / $dt1 ); // 50
```